# Remove duplicates based on the "serial no" column, Using the unique comma separated names independent of order using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

required Python Panda code for following expected output

Input:

| memberid | serial no | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B | A |
| 1 | B,A | B |
| 1 | A,B | B |
| 1 | B,A | A |

Expected Output : after removing duplicates

| memberid | serial no | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B | A |
| 1 | A,B | B |

Note:Column B  may have more than 2 comma separated values and that many duplicate records also

Input have lot of duplicate values as it has taken by writing unest function in postgres sql query . want to remove the duplicates by writing pandas script

Comment: the logic is unclear, you want to remove duplicates based on the "serial no" column? Using the unique comma separated names independent of order?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a temporary column with the comma separated values as [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```
(df.assign(n=df['serial no'].str.split(',').apply(frozenset))
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['memberid', 'n', 'Serial'])
   .drop(columns='n')
)
```

Or:

```
(df.assign(n=df['serial no'].apply(lambda x: frozenset(x.split(','))))
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['memberid', 'n', 'Serial'])
   .drop(columns='n')
)
```

Output:

```
   memberid serial no Serial
0         1       A,B      A
1         1       B,A      B
```

Different order:

```
(df.assign(n=df['serial no'].str.split(',').apply(frozenset))
   .sort_values(by=['memberid', 'serial no', 'Serial'])
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['memberid', 'n', 'Serial'])
   .drop(columns='n')
)
```

Output:

```
   memberid serial no Serial
0         1       A,B      A
2         1       A,B      B
```